# get osm data directly from database for pgrouting

Tags: routes, postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I am creating an application which requires a route finder.

I have OSM data stored in a PostGIS database and currently this data may be manipulated by my application e.g. roads may be moved, added or deleted.

I was looking into pgRouting however it seems like it needs OSM data to be either in an .osm format or a shape file.

Is it possible for pgRouting to access my OSM tables directly to build its graph? If not is there any other routing system out there that can?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this [page](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/). At section 6. you will see, pgrouting works with SQL queries. It doesn't able to handle osm or shape files directly, they are just data sources for import.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you load the OSM data with the tool osm2pgrouting to your database. This tool creates an sql command which you can load into the database.

[Here](http://pgrouting.org/docs/tools/osm2pgrouting.html) you can find some information about it.